# Email attachments with `MIME::Lite::TT::HTML`

Tags: perl, email

I'm trying to use `MIME::Lite::TT::HTML` for sending emails. It works great, but I can't figure out how to use it with attachments.

I tried this:

```
$msg->attr("content-type"  => "multipart/mixed"); 
$msg->attach(Type => $mime,
             Path => $attachment,
             Filename => $name, );
```

But it breaks the message. The HTML and TXT parts are no longer interpreted as being the same thing, and the content is therefore displayed twice.

So what is the correct way of adding attachments using `MIME::Lite::TT::HTML`?

Comment: How are you creating `$msg` in the first place?  I think you're better off not mucking with the Content-Type directly after the message is created.  Just create a new message, attach what you want to attach, and let the library take care of supplying a suitable type.

Comment: @tripleee Well, I'm using pretty much the same code, that is in the documentation (minus the encoding stuff) http://search.cpan.org/~chunzi/MIME-Lite-TT-HTML-0.03/lib/MIME/Lite/TT/HTML.pm

Comment: So if you omit the `$msg->attr()` invocation, do you get better results?

Comment: @tripleee No. If I don't set `multipart/mixed`, the attachments are not sent at all.

Comment: Do you really need the TT stuff then? Seems like maybe you're going to have to work around its limitations, perhaps by using the bare MIME::Lite.

Comment: @tripleee Unfortunately I need the TT stuff. But it seems that the `MIME::Lite::TT` works. Seems that you can't have an email that has both alternative parts and attachments.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the TT stuff but I'm thinking maybe you want the attachments to show up from inside the HTML?  The proper structure for that would be (multipart/alternative text (multipart/related html image image ...)) not (multipart/mixed text html image image ...) and it's looking to me like maybe this is hard or impossible to do with TT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that an email can't both have alternative parts and attachments.

I settled with `MINE::Lite::TT` which seems to work fine with the code. There just won't be any HTML emails for now :-/

Comment: You're mistaken, MIME messages can have both multipart/mixed and multipart/alternative by correctly nesting MIME parts. If you're looking for modern email creation modules: http://p3rl.org/Courriel::Builder http://p3rl.org/Email::MIME::Kit and probably others in the `Email::MIME::` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter a similar problem attaching a PDF file and a template HTML with dynamic image and fields(name, profession), I also use the `MIME::Lite::TT::HTML` and other libraries.

The problem is, if you didn't separate the template or you didn't include the library `HTML::Template;` it will both send a text and html file in the body of the email with attachment. The template only use a 'text/html'.

Here's the snippet of the working code:
Just change the variable to suits your needs:

Template html - `test2.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><TMPL_VAR NAME=profession></title>
    </head>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src=<TMPL_VAR NAME=photo> alt="my photo" width="700"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td>
            <TMPL_VAR NAME=applicantname>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is for the: `email.pl`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Lite::TT::HTML;
#use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 );
use Authen::SASL;
use Net::SSL;
use HTML::Template;

my $from_address = 'no-reply@abc.com';
my $to_address = 'to@address.com';
my $mail_host = '';
my $mail_user = '';
my $mail_password = '';
my $mail_port = 25;

my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'test2.html');
$template->param(applicantname => "Applicant name");
$template->param(profession => "Designer");
$template->param(photo => "photo location or url path");

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
   From =>     $from_address,
   To =>       $to_address,
   Subject =>  'Applicant Resume',
   Type =>     'text/html',
   Data =>     $template->output()
);
$msg->attach (
   Type => 'application/pdf',
   Path => 'C:\Users\downloadfiles/filetest.pdf',
   Filename => 'filetest.pdf',
   Disposition => 'attachment'
) or die "Error adding : $!\n";

$msg->send('smtp',$mail_host,HELLO=>$mail_host,PORT=>$mail_port,AuthUser=>$mail_user,AuthPass=>$mail_password,Timeout=>60);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the mime-type should be multipart/alternative

Comment: If I set `multipart/alternative` then the attachments are skipped completely.